# Why does GitHub issue GetAssertion requests when trying to register a new security key

Tags: github, webauthn, fido

I'm working on a fido2 authenticator library and found some odd behavior regarding the security key registration process on Github:

I've previously registered two keys and now I want to add another one.

After the `getInfo` API call, Github seams to make a `authenticatorGetAssertion` call for every key already registered. This is probably their way to check if the key has already been registered or not (just a guess). Both `GetAssertion` requests fail with `CTAP2_ERR_NO_CREDENTIALS`.

```
YubiKey 5:

FIDODebug[11:35:56] -> {1: "packed", 2: h'3AEB002460381C6F258E8395D3026F571F0D9A76488DCD837639B13AED3165604100000000FA2B99DC9E3942578F924A30D23C41180040EDA043B6EDD805976A4E2EFFCC84381FFC601E5301C9DB1D7C887035176EC83889AC86398FDEA2A5F1A57C11AF4AE0484ED51C5C2F121B2454D6F9FAD6E187FBA5010203262001215820DBCDD8CC3C667D6776F25181BB950063B3CF99AE58D014ADD021E4F1D7E040EE225820D0E6ED4CCB2742BF0C1287CA451D94C779CED73B415BA2ACC88689D79B5444F4', 3: {"alg": -7, "sig": h'3045022100A886B4C3E3E4EC63E602C4466B614DEDA02CE7815F67DF2F15F9D45F657857A902203881D5080A3107DA0E17DA9CD9841EC55D5A470CCB01C379A416230771542F4E', "x5c": [h'308202BC308201A4A003020102020403ADF012300D06092A864886F70D01010B0500302E312C302A0603550403132359756269636F2055324620526F6F742043412053657269616C203435373230303633313020170D3134303830313030303030305A180F32303530303930343030303030305A306D310B300906035504061302534531123010060355040A0C0959756269636F20414231223020060355040B0C1941757468656E74696361746F72204174746573746174696F6E3126302406035504030C1D59756269636F205532462045452053657269616C2036313733303833343059301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D03010703420004199E879C162DB7DC39EE4A42A04616A5B309FECA092F76BE0948F96D6E95CAE4CC65CD54A059CFBDC7C9B31B2B1D6C184479C2C061F418AA954B596A2C1CFA17A36C306A302206092B0601040182C40A020415312E332E362E312E342E312E34313438322E312E373013060B2B0601040182E51C0201010404030204303021060B2B0601040182E51C01010404120410FA2B99DC9E3942578F924A30D23C4118300C0603551D130101FF04023000300D06092A864886F70D01010B0500038201010028EBB367FED1D8F0E289EBCA9FF6D80757C60E9AE57CB1728C9B1C38CABBBD84D9237DA831AC21949F0F2DFC0C316BFDB175B36E63A22BBB580EADCA5280D079840E5A1E2572625A3BFB876033DBFB22A969C938B89CE171359400A1252D9702A91293D54519E960DD22CE8A27EB05EB7E79B750C002FED9016B711EC9AD74501BD914CBBE8ED9571281B74F44EB077CE61ECB06AB85A97255267EE8E3982BF43F0CB21A382D235EB9E4CE6DB298C405425040232B2B61E10CD70C6215BC03B7E94071B70E12D1C47F96655A2EF99D4CE55A7F1B4B1FF914EE136D9E612047148864698880443116653889B86486D9C9C9FFBC9385453569B345744B8CA0B437']}}

FIDODebug[11:35:54] <- 1 {1: h'E782C8D2E0AD4ADDF8271928D8B37746EDE1B30AD92DA8F9DEB96E8280B4AA2F', 2: {"id": "github.com", "name": "GitHub"}, 3: {"id": h'C0BBBCEA3161953E45CDB3C75D28C38C3B08D5BDEA6458CE83E62E0E1B81F1FE0B3D4FFD2D9ADCF935409365AB50DDFB122139A301C0BA081B987895EE601C77', "name": "r4gus", "displayName": "David Sugar"}, 4: [{"alg": -7, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -257, "type": "public-key"}]}

FIDODebug[11:35:54] -> (CTAP2 error code 46)

FIDODebug[11:35:54] <- 2 {1: "github.com", 2: h'E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855', 3: [{"id": h'A321BA23BFBACD2362664B5A44CC5399BC805BC66D47741D967890321F3C486BA84CA5D586B5AA5A63F6EBF7B12429756835C3930D3460678196C70EF88AD4C3', "type": "public-key"}], 5: {"up": false}}

FIDODebug[11:35:54] -> (CTAP2 error code 46)

FIDODebug[11:35:54] <- 2 {1: "github.com", 2: h'E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855', 3: [{"id": h'182F151E610E171BBD5F7579E7908F0EBFE3AF8D7217BF6812234AA7021F4304656CD7E128C28B8509C0636F57EC69FA867884BAD906A2E53552F6DBE6ED1120', "type": "public-key"}], 5: {"up": false}}

FIDODebug[11:35:54] -> (CTAP2 error code 46)

FIDODebug[11:35:54] <- 2 {1: "https://github.com/u2f/trusted_facets", 2: h'E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855', 3: [{"id": h'A321BA23BFBACD2362664B5A44CC5399BC805BC66D47741D967890321F3C486BA84CA5D586B5AA5A63F6EBF7B12429756835C3930D3460678196C70EF88AD4C3', "type": "public-key"}], 5: {"up": false}}

FIDODebug[11:35:54] -> (CTAP2 error code 46)

FIDODebug[11:35:54] <- 2 {1: "https://github.com/u2f/trusted_facets", 2: h'E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855', 3: [{"id": h'182F151E610E171BBD5F7579E7908F0EBFE3AF8D7217BF6812234AA7021F4304656CD7E128C28B8509C0636F57EC69FA867884BAD906A2E53552F6DBE6ED1120', "type": "public-key"}], 5: {"up": false}}

FIDODebug[11:35:54] The device supports the CTAP2 protocol.

FIDODebug[11:35:54] -> {1: ["U2F_V2", "FIDO_2_0"], 2: ["hmac-secret"], 3: h'FA2B99DC9E3942578F924A30D23C4118', 4: {"rk": true, "up": true, "plat": false, "clientPin": false}, 5: 1200, 6: [1]}

FIDODebug[11:35:53] Discovery session started.

FIDODebug[11:35:53] Sending CTAP2 AuthenticatorGetInfo request to authenticator.

FIDODebug[11:35:53] BLE adapter address 6C:6A:77:A0:F9:FF

FIDODebug[11:35:53] Android accessory discovery started

FIDODebug[11:35:53] Found 0 caBLEv2 devices
```

The problem I see is that this doesn't reflect the [spec](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.1-ps-20210615/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.1-ps-errata-20220621.html#authenticatorMakeCredential) as far as I understand it.

This leads to an error if I enforce user verification, even when setting the `alwaysUv` flag, because the `authenticatorGetAssertion` request omits the `pinUvAuthParam` parameter.

```
custom:

FIDODebug[11:59:22] -> (CTAP2 error code 49)

FIDODebug[11:59:18] <- 2 {1: "https://github.com/u2f/trusted_facets", 2: h'E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855', 3: [{"id": h'182F151E610E171BBD5F7579E7908F0EBFE3AF8D7217BF6812234AA7021F4304656CD7E128C28B8509C0636F57EC69FA867884BAD906A2E53552F6DBE6ED1120', "type": "public-key"}], 5: {"up": false}}

FIDODebug[11:59:18] The device supports the CTAP2 protocol.

FIDODebug[11:59:18] -> {1: ["FIDO_2_0", "FIDO_2_1"], 3: h'6F158274AAB6443D9BCF8A3F69297C88', 4: {"rk": false, "up": true, "uv": false, "plat": true, "alwaysUv": true, "clientPin": true, "pinUvAuthToken": true, "makeCredUvNotRqd": false, "noMcGaPermissionsWithClientPin": false}, 6: [2], 9: ["usb"], 10: [{"alg": -7, "type": "public-key"}], 14: 51966}
```

After receiving the first `CTAP2_ERR_PIN_INVALID` no further assertion requests are issued and Github will display `Security key registration failed.`

In comparison, the impl works for example with Codeberg.

For both `authenticatorMakeCredential` and `authenticatorGetAssertion` the spec says:

```
1. If authenticator supports either pinUvAuthToken or clientPin features and the platform sends a zero length pinUvAuthParam:

    1. Request evidence of user interaction in an authenticator-specific way (e.g., flash the LED light).

    2. If the user declines permission, or the operation times out, then end the operation by returning CTAP2_ERR_OPERATION_DENIED.

    3. If evidence of user interaction is provided in this step then return either CTAP2_ERR_PIN_NOT_SET if PIN is not set or CTAP2_ERR_PIN_INVALID if PIN has been set.
```

So a implementation that adheres to the spec will return `CTAP2_ERR_PIN_INVALID` before we can check if the given credential exists or not.

Does anyone know if this behavior is common with other implementations and/ or reflects an older ctap spec?

I would expect the following behavior:

```
FIDODebug[12:23:46] -> {1: "packed", 2: h'54B06FBA8D07757301B093071D8CDF891BCDE3D7F13612FEB3FB1FD86D21FA9345000000006F158274AAB6443D9BCF8A3F69297C880040F95BEBC0A6EE527B85ED1FBA12B7C8E6960BB1DADC5FD7DF768BA5684E449A8E3DBE4782333F37168C83FAFF3B2147F376BBAB17E40FB3DD8A8A35061B932C3EA60102032620012158203F4AAB317DD060BF7399F1D19DC43C423038F61604C438D2DD84A5FB6FA7296E2258202CC58E3AB2AF86A225A75DF3F3D43D496BC1C2F08E4BF0D23E85233C4094321C2358205BA74E18264AEA3E049099B3CE49352E916400A495BB0F3DA34E2E2B66C73B1F', 3: {"alg": "Es256", "sig": h'304402206275A1022E010833818B9F3A52A629D3FFE0C721DEDF3882CD4EDFBBF0A6EF190220607FD3C4423108DC6BC1D91A4A7A1018F3094B0DD221B4379F141866F3F07089'}}

FIDODebug[12:23:41] <- 1 {1: h'F9B272A975C33E3E6D01DA61A020462BD7A4F5895F95D2F90259081778DCEC55', 2: {"id": "codeberg.org", "name": "Codeberg.org"}, 3: {"id": h'B4A7080000000000', "name": "r4gus", "displayName": "David Sugar"}, 4: [{"alg": -7, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -35, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -36, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -257, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -258, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -259, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -37, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -38, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -39, "type": "public-key"}, {"alg": -8, "type": "public-key"}], 8: h'52F1621659FC1E4918F7E9D1B5F36DCA0E932E1F0EFAE6E7CE9A1F861A865D35', 9: 2}

FIDODebug[12:23:41] -> {2: h'15CFD3213A708811FECB288A782720D1E5BBA1E1C9486FC4ABE130522B7875A2935834B42F2161A9ABBE1DEDCB076A0E'}

FIDODebug[12:23:41] <- 6 {1: 2, 2: 9, 3: {1: 2, 3: -25, -1: 1, -2: h'A31362152EC002890873DDC70CC546D86C2D6925296F3679E3A1D5A798E89361', -3: h'1D557E224D36218759EF5B6F25525FF31A907F7AB97BF634A6A22EF03A818616'}, 6: h'0174E6862BCF871ABD26F9AC56BA05804A433D06B39A7C13A965B07DE6D52D78', 9: 3, 10: "codeberg.org"}

FIDODebug[12:23:41] -> {1: {1: 2, 3: -25, -1: 1, -2: h'B0972D6924BCEE5A6DAD51254DB0BE9A7D99D51515B9066A7D40EA4CA120DBA6', -3: h'37F40038A01A1DAAB56216C8D26E79E7113CB7E3430ADC077AF58FDAC767996E'}}

FIDODebug[12:23:41] <- 6 {1: 2, 2: 2}

FIDODebug[12:23:39] -> {3: 8, 4: false}

FIDODebug[12:23:39] <- 6 {1: 2, 2: 1}

FIDODebug[12:23:39] The device supports the CTAP2 protocol.

FIDODebug[12:23:39] -> {1: ["FIDO_2_0", "FIDO_2_1"], 3: h'6F158274AAB6443D9BCF8A3F69297C88', 4: {"rk": false, "up": true, "uv": false, "plat": true, "alwaysUv": true, "clientPin": true, "pinUvAuthToken": true, "makeCredUvNotRqd": false, "noMcGaPermissionsWithClientPin": false}, 6: [2], 9: ["usb"], 10: [{"alg": -7, "type": "public-key"}], 14: 51966}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probing the excludeList with getAssertions is done because authenticators have a limit to the maximum message size that they can handle. Thus sending the excludeList (with can be quite large) in a single makeCredential request will fail in some cases and there's no way to split an excludeList in the makeCredential call.

So the excludeList in CTAP2 is often unused in practice.

GitHub is setting appIdExclude, so the probe needs to check the AppID first. A pinUvAuthToken cannot be used for this because PUATs become specific to the RP ID that you use them with, and the PUAT is needed for the final makeCredential, thus cannot be used for AppID probing. That should be fine because credentials created with AppIDs must have been created using the old U2F web API and that never supported credProtect, and never worked for alwaysUv authenticators.

From [the spec](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.2-rd-20230321/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.2-rd-20230321.html#sctn-getAssert-authnr-alg) for getAssertion:

> If the alwaysUv option ID is present and true and the "up" option is present and true then:

But the up option is *not* present and true here, and there are no other mentions of alwaysUv in the getAssertion processing steps.

You quote the section with "If authenticator supports either pinUvAuthToken or clientPin features and the platform sends a zero length pinUvAuthParam:", but that doesn't apply either because the pinUvAuthToken is not zero length, it's omitted. (Those are different things.)

Comment: I see, this totally makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are speaking specifically about the CTAP interface between the client (of which Github is an RP) and the authenticator you are building?

Github is likely supplying a list of known credential handles with the account, requesting the authenticators holding those credentials be excluded from the registration. The client is using those handles with a no-user-presence check to ask attached authenticators if they were the ones which issued the credential. I can't speak to why the client would take this approach rather than using the exclude list, other than it not fully supporting CTAP 2.x or being in a U2F fallback mode.

I suppose it could also be behavior exclusive to Github and a few other sites, as Github uses a registration-time extension to exclude U2F-style RPID facets. That would mean a degenerative case where the requests have to be tried against two different RPIDs.

Comment: I can pretty much rule out that the client doesn't support CTAP 2.x because I used the same client (Brave browser) for the expected behavior example. Question becomes how some kind of fallback mode gets triggered , especially because the client should know that the authenticator doesn't support older versions by looking at the versions field of the `GetInfo` response.